# Youtube restricted video play

Tags: ios, youtube

I have read [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) document on how to play youtube video in iOS app. But for some video I am getting error "Restricted Video.

This app is playing restricted video also.'Musify Video Tube For YouTube - Free Music Player and Streamer'

Which player or SDK or api to play restricted video?

Comment: This looks like it may have some legal implications.

Comment: How we can do same in our application? for legal implications whom to contact? or how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution with this https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit.

*Yes its against terms and condition of youtube.